# Opening VS2008 Project from VSS under Windows7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I have a fresh install of VS2008 and VSS under Windows 7. When opening a project I get a file requester that has a Source Safe icon on the left, but when I click it, there's nothing listed. I've launched VSS and setup my repository and that's all good. How do I open VSS projects? Never had this issue until Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up source safe folder and login first. Do this under Tools \ Options \ Source Control.

Then you do File \ Open From Source Control instead of File \ Open

Comment: Thanks Raj, but all that is already configured. The repository path and everything is there. It just doesn't show up in the Open dialog.